# не возвращается значение переменной

Tags: c++, sfml

Почему переменная Colr colr в функции void initNewBall() не меняет значение при вызове функции Colr initColor()?

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;
using namespace sf;


constexpr unsigned BALLS_COUNT = 4;
const string WINDOW_TITLE = "Moving balls";
static const sf::Color BACKGROUND_COLOR = sf::Color(0, 0, 0);
constexpr unsigned WINDOW_WIDTH = 800;
constexpr unsigned WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600;

struct Colr
{
    int red;
    int green;
    int blue;

    bool operator<(const Colr& curr) const
    {
        if (red < curr.red)
        {
           return true;
        }
        else if (red == curr.red)
        {
            if (green < curr.green)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if (green == curr.green)
            {
                return blue < curr.blue;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
};

struct Ball
{
    CircleShape shape;
    Vector2f offset;
};

struct PRNG
{
    std::mt19937 engine;
};

void initGenerator(PRNG&);
size_t random_index(PRNG&, int); // Генерирует индекс в диапазоне [0, size)
bool checkBGColor(Colr&);
Colr initColor(PRNG, set<Colr>&);
float setBallPosition(float, float);
void initNewBall(PRNG, vector<Ball>&, Ball&, set<Colr>&);
void pollEvents(RenderWindow&, PRNG, vector<Ball>&, Ball&, set<Colr>&);
float length(const Vector2f&);
float distance(const Ball&, const Ball&);
float dot(const Vector2f&, const Vector2f&);
float sqr(float);
Vector2f getSpeedAfterStrike(const Ball&, const Ball&);
void update(vector<Ball>&, float);
void redrawFrame(RenderWindow&, vector<Ball>&);
void initDefaultPlayGround(PRNG, vector<Ball>&, Ball&, set<Colr>&);
void init(PRNG, set<Colr>&, vector<Ball>&, Ball&);

int main()
{
    Clock clock;
    ContextSettings settings;
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode({WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT}), WINDOW_TITLE, Style::Default, settings);
    vector<Ball> balls(BALLS_COUNT);
    PRNG generator;
    Ball ball;
    set<Colr> isColrs; 

    initGenerator(generator);
    init(generator, isColrs, balls, ball);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        float deltaTime = clock.restart().asSeconds();
        pollEvents(window, generator, balls, ball, isColrs);
        update(balls, deltaTime);
        redrawFrame(window, balls);
    }
}


void initGenerator(PRNG& generator)
{
    // Используем время с 1 января 1970 года в секундах как случайное зерно
    const unsigned seed = unsigned(std::time(nullptr));
    generator.engine.seed(seed);
}

size_t random_index(PRNG& generator, int size)
{
    // Создаём распределение
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0, size - 1);

    // Вычисляем псевдослучайное число: вызовем распределение как функцию,
    //  передав генератор произвольных целых чисел как аргумент.
    return distribution(generator.engine);
}

bool checkBGColor(Colr& colr)
{
    if((colr.red != BACKGROUND_COLOR.r) && (colr.green != BACKGROUND_COLOR.g) && (colr.blue != BACKGROUND_COLOR.b))
    {
        return 1;
    }    
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }    

}

Colr initColor(PRNG generator, set<Colr>& isColrs)
{
    Colr colr;
    colr.red = random_index(generator, 256);
    colr.green = random_index(generator, 256);
    colr.blue = random_index(generator, 256);
    if(isColrs.empty() || (isColrs.find(colr) == isColrs.end()) && checkBGColor(colr))
    {
        isColrs.insert(colr);
        cout << "New color: " << colr.red << " " << colr.green << " " << colr.blue << " is complete to be return" << endl << endl;
        return colr;
    }
    else
    {
        initColor(generator, isColrs);        
    }
}

float setBallPosition(float left, float right)
{
    return (left - right); 
}

void initNewBall(PRNG generator, vector<Ball>& balls, Ball& ball, set<Colr>& isColrs)
{
    const float currSize = 40;

    ball.offset.x = random_index(generator, 250);
    ball.offset.y = random_index(generator, 250);
    ball.shape.setRadius(currSize);
    Colr colr = initColor(generator, isColrs);
    cout << "current color is: " << colr.red << " " << colr.green << " " << colr.blue << endl << endl;
    ball.shape.setFillColor(sf::Color(colr.red, colr.green, colr.blue));
    ball.shape.setPosition(random_index(generator, setBallPosition(WINDOW_WIDTH, ball.shape.getRadius())), random_index(generator, setBallPosition(WINDOW_HEIGHT, ball.shape.getRadius())));    
    ball.shape.setOrigin(ball.shape.getRadius(), ball.shape.getRadius());
    balls.insert(balls.end(), ball);

    for (size_t fi = 0; fi < balls.size(); ++fi)
    {
        for (size_t si = fi + 1; si < balls.size(); ++si)
        {
            Ball& first = balls[fi];
            Ball& second = balls[si];
            while((distance(first, second) <= (first.shape.getRadius() + second.shape.getRadius())) || (balls.at(si).shape.getPosition().x <= balls.at(si).shape.getRadius()) || (balls.at(si).shape.getPosition().y <= balls.at(si).shape.getRadius()))
            {
                balls.at(si).shape.setPosition(random_index(generator, setBallPosition(WINDOW_WIDTH, balls.at(si).shape.getRadius())), random_index(generator, setBallPosition(WINDOW_HEIGHT, balls.at(si).shape.getRadius())));
                balls.at(si).shape.setOrigin(balls.at(si).shape.getRadius(), balls.at(si).shape.getRadius());
            }
        }
    }
}

void pollEvents(RenderWindow& window, PRNG generator, vector<Ball>& balls, Ball& ball, set<Colr>& isColrs)
{
    Event event{};
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        switch (event.type)
        {
        case Event::Closed:
            window.close();
            break;
        case Event::MouseButtonReleased:
            if(event.mouseButton.button == sf::Mouse::Left)
            {
                initNewBall(generator, balls, ball, isColrs);    
            }    
            break;    
        default:
            break;  
        }
    }
}

float length(const Vector2f& value)
{
    return std::hypot(value.x, value.y);
}

float distance(const Ball& ball, const Ball& curr)
{
    return length(ball.shape.getPosition() - curr.shape.getPosition());
}


float dot(const Vector2f& left, const Vector2f& right)
{
    return left.x * right.x + left.y * right.y;
}

float sqr(float value)
{
    return value * value;
}

Vector2f getSpeedAfterStrike(const Ball& first, const Ball& second)
{
    const Vector2f deltaSpeed = first.offset - second.offset;
    const Vector2f deltaPos = first.shape.getPosition() - second.shape.getPosition();
    return first.offset - deltaPos * (dot(deltaSpeed, deltaPos) / sqr(length(deltaPos)));
}

void update(vector<Ball>& balls, float deltaTime)
{
    constexpr float MAX_DELTA_TIME = 0.01f;
    deltaTime = std::min(deltaTime, MAX_DELTA_TIME);

    for (auto& ball: balls)
    {
        if ((ball.shape.getPosition().x >= WINDOW_WIDTH - ball.shape.getRadius()) || (ball.shape.getPosition().y >= WINDOW_HEIGHT - ball.shape.getRadius())
        || (ball.shape.getPosition().x <= ball.shape.getRadius()) || (ball.shape.getPosition().y <= ball.shape.getRadius()))
        {
            ball.offset = -ball.offset;
        }
    }

    for (size_t fi = 0; fi < balls.size(); ++fi)
    {
        for (size_t si = fi + 1; si < balls.size(); ++si)
        {
            Ball& first = balls[fi];
            Ball& second = balls[si];
            if(distance(first, second) <= (first.shape.getRadius() + second.shape.getRadius()))
            {  
                const Vector2f newFirstSpeed = getSpeedAfterStrike(first, second);
                const Vector2f newSecondSpeed = getSpeedAfterStrike(second, first);
                first.offset = newFirstSpeed;
                second.offset = newSecondSpeed;
            }
        }
    }

    for (auto& ball: balls)
    {
        ball.shape.move(ball.offset * deltaTime);
    }
}

void redrawFrame(RenderWindow& window, vector<Ball>& balls)
{
    window.clear(BACKGROUND_COLOR);
    for (auto& ball: balls)
    {
        window.draw(ball.shape);        
    }
    window.display();
}

void initDefaultPlayGround(PRNG generator, vector<Ball>& balls, Ball& ball, set<Colr>& isColrs)
{
    const vector<float> sizes = {
        40,
        40,
        40,
        40
    };    

    for (int i = 0; i < BALLS_COUNT; ++i)
    {
        balls.at(i).offset.x = random_index(generator, 250);
        balls.at(i).offset.y = random_index(generator, 250);
        balls.at(i).shape.setRadius(sizes.at(i));
        Colr colr = initColor(generator, isColrs);
        balls.at(i).shape.setFillColor(sf::Color(colr.red, colr.green, colr.blue));
        balls.at(i).shape.setPosition(random_index(generator, setBallPosition(WINDOW_WIDTH, balls.at(i).shape.getRadius())), random_index(generator, setBallPosition(WINDOW_HEIGHT, balls.at(i).shape.getRadius())));    
        balls.at(i).shape.setOrigin(balls.at(i).shape.getRadius(), balls.at(i).shape.getRadius());

        for (size_t fi = 0; fi < balls.size(); ++fi)
        {
            while((balls.at(fi).shape.getPosition().x <= balls.at(fi).shape.getRadius()) || (balls.at(fi).shape.getPosition().y <= balls.at(fi).shape.getRadius()))
            {
                balls.at(fi).shape.setPosition(random_index(generator, setBallPosition(WINDOW_WIDTH, balls.at(fi).shape.getRadius())), random_index(generator, setBallPosition(WINDOW_HEIGHT, balls.at(fi).shape.getRadius())));
                balls.at(fi).shape.setOrigin(balls.at(fi).shape.getRadius(), balls.at(fi).shape.getRadius());
            }

            for (size_t si = fi + 1; si < balls.size(); ++si)
            {
                Ball& first = balls[fi];
                Ball& second = balls[si];
                while((distance(first, second) <= (first.shape.getRadius() + second.shape.getRadius())) || (balls.at(si).shape.getPosition().x <= balls.at(si).shape.getRadius()) || (balls.at(si).shape.getPosition().y <= balls.at(si).shape.getRadius()))
                {
                    balls.at(si).shape.setPosition(random_index(generator, setBallPosition(WINDOW_WIDTH, balls.at(si).shape.getRadius())), random_index(generator, setBallPosition(WINDOW_HEIGHT, balls.at(si).shape.getRadius())));
                    balls.at(si).shape.setOrigin(balls.at(si).shape.getRadius(), balls.at(si).shape.getRadius());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void init(PRNG generator, set<Colr>& isColrs, vector<Ball>& balls, Ball& ball)
{
    initDefaultPlayGround(generator, balls, ball, isColrs);
}
```

Comment: В вашей `initColor` не все пути выполнения возвращают значение через `return`: в первой ветке `if` есть `return`, а во второй - нет. Поведение не определено.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, проблема здесь:

```
Colr initColor(PRNG generator, set<Colr>& isColrs)
{
    Colr colr;
    colr.red = random_index(generator, 256);
    colr.green = random_index(generator, 256);
    colr.blue = random_index(generator, 256);
    if(isColrs.empty() || (isColrs.find(colr) == isColrs.end()) && checkBGColor(colr))
    {
        isColrs.insert(colr);
        cout << "New color: " << colr.red << " " << colr.green << " " << colr.blue << " is complete to be return" << endl << endl;
        return colr;
    }
    else
    {
        initColor(generator, isColrs);        
    }
}
```

Перед рекурсивным вызовом initColor (предпредпоследняя строчка) должен быть return.

Comment: Colr initColor() генерирует нужный цвет, но почему-то он не передается в void initNewBall(), переменная Colr colr принимает цвет первого элемента из set<Colr> isColrs.

Comment: Происходит ли рекурсивный вызов initColor во второй ветке при этом? Если да, то причина - отсутствующий return. Вы формируете значение, но оно никуда не возвращается.